# Global variable becomes undefined after being assigned new value in function

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables

I am having trouble understanding why several global variables are becoming undefined after I set their value and `console.log` them in a function.

To set up the exercise, I am trying to make a restaurant menu builder. Given an object, `burgerJoint`, containing info from a restaurant's menu such as main courses, sides, and drinks, I am attempting to filter the values into matching groups, map them to some marketing verbiage then print it all out in groups.

```
var burgerJoint = {
  name: 'Americana',
  menuItems: [
    { name: 'burger', type: 'main' },
    { name: 'hotdog', type: '' },
    { name: 'chicken sammich', type: 'main' },
    { name: 'root beer', type: 'drink' },
    { name: 'tuna melt', type: 'main' },
    { name: 'fries', type: 'side' },
    { name: 'iced tea', type: 'drink' },
    { name: 'onion rings', type: 'side' },
  ],
  mainsType: 'Single or double',
  sidesMarketing: ['crisp', 'piping-hot'],
  drinkMarketing: 'Small, medium, or large',
};

/// accessible variables to allow for future changes

var mains = ["aa"];   ///problem variable "aa" for troubleshooting
var sides = ["bb"];   ///problem variable "bb" for troubleshooting
var drinks = ["cc"];  ///problem variable "cc" for troubleshooting

console.log(mains);    ///outputs "aa" as expected

function menuSection(restaraunt, type) {
  section = restaraunt.menuItems.filter(function(food) {
    return food.type === type;
  });
  type === "main" ? mains = mainSection(restaraunt, section) :
  type === "side" ? sides = sideSection(restaraunt, section) :
  type === "drink" ? drinks = drinkSection(restaraunt, section) : 
  alert("Type is invalid");
}

function mainSection(restaraunt, mainsKeyVal) {
  mains = mainsKeyVal.map(function(food) {
    return restaraunt.mainsType + " " + food.name;
  });
  console.log(mains.join("\n"));  ///outputs correct info
}

function sideSection(restaraunt, sidesKeyVal) {
  sides = sidesKeyVal.map(function(food) {
    return restaraunt.sidesMarketing[0] + " " + food.name;
  });
  console.log(sides.join("\n"));  ///outputs correct info
}

function drinkSection(restaraunt, drinksKeyVal) {
  drinks = drinksKeyVal.map(function(food) {
    return restaraunt.drinkMarketing + " " + food.name;
  });
  console.log(drinks.join("\n"));  ///outputs correct info
}

function menuBuilder(restaraunt) {

  console.log(mains);  ///outputs "aa"
  console.log(sides);  ///outputs "bb"
  console.log(drinks); ///outputs "cc"

  menuSection(restaraunt, "main");
  menuSection(restaraunt, "side");
  menuSection(restaraunt, "drink");

  console.log(mains);  ///outputs undefined
  console.log(sides);  ///outputs undefined
  console.log(drinks); ///outputs undefined
}
menuBuilder(burgerJoint);
console.log(mains);  ///outputs undefined
console.log(sides);  ///outputs undefined
console.log(drinks); ///outputs undefined
```

The three variables, `mains`, `sides`, and `drinks`, when referred to by `console.log`from inside `mainSection`, `drinkSection`, and `sideSection` produces the desired output. When referred to inside `menuBuilder` before the three `xxxxSection` functions, they retain their original values as expected. When using `console.log` inside `menuBuilder` after the other three functions, the variables are now undefined.

When stepping through the code in Chrome's debugging tool, each variable becomes `undefined` after being called by the `console.log` in their respective `xxxxxSection` function. What is causing them to become undefined?

Comment: As an aside, I suggest using a `switch` if you want to compare `type` against several values like this. The `?:` operator should be used sparingly as it's often difficult to follow, especially when you nest them. It can be really useful when you need an `if` in the middle of another expression but in general it's clearer to use a proper `if` and `else` (or `switch` in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got this:

```
mains = mainSection(restaraunt, section)
```

but `mainSection` doesn't return anything, so the return value is implicitly `undefined`.

You could fix it by removing the `mains =` from that line (and the equivalent lines for your other types) though it might be better if you returned a value from `mainSection` rather than relying on closures to pass values between function calls, e.g.:

```
function mainSection(restaurant, mainsKeyVal) {
    return mainsKeyVal.map(function(food) {
        return restaurant.mainsType + " " + food.name;
    });
}
```

This function doesn't have any 'side-effects', it just uses the values passed in to calculate the return value.

Comment: Removing the `main =` gave me the desired result. Could you elaborate on what you mean by returning the value from `mainSection`? Is there another way that I could map the mainsType onto the values that have the key `"main"`? It does feel unwieldy but I wanted to keep them separate because `mainSection`, `sideSection`, and `drinkSection` behave slightly differently.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example of returning from `mainSection`. It no longer assigns a value to `mains`, that would now be done by putting back in the `mains =` that you had in your original code.